# using maven variables defined in two separate profiles

Tags: maven-2, maven, profiles

I have two profiles in my pom.xml, dev and stage:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <hostname>vl-wlp1.hk.oracle.com</hostname>
        </properties>
        <id>stage</id>
        <properties>
            <hostname>vl-wcfs.hk.oracle.com</hostname>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And I'd like use these in my site documentation at:

```
src/site/apt/index.apt
```

like so:

```
Dev Site: ${dev.hostname}
Stage Site: ${stage.hostname}
```

Can I do that or something else that has the same effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not without a huge hack, no.

If you want to read both property values independently, they will have to be two different properties.

How about a pragmatic solution like this:

```
<properties>
    <dev.host>vl-wlp1.hk.oracle.com</dev.host>
    <stage.host>vl-wcfs.hk.oracle.com</stage.host>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <hostname>${dev.host}</hostname>
        </properties>
        <id>stage</id>
        <properties>
            <hostname>${stage.host}</hostname>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

src/site/apt/index.apt:

```
Dev Site: ${dev.host}
Stage Site: ${stage.host}
```

---

(The huge hack mentioned above would mean programmatically iterating over the current project's profiles and parsing each profile's properties manually, you *could* do that in a custom maven plugin or in a Groovy Script using [GMaven](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Home))

Comment: How to use host name in Java code according to build profile?

Comment: @manurajhada You should ask a separate question, but: take the host name from a property file and run that through maven resource filtering